# Angular's ng-if not working on view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

some days ago i have tried to work with `ng-if` even then my code works but now when i am trying it ,`ng-if` not working

here is how i am doing inside `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="program in getProgram">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{program.name}}</td>
    <td>{{program.code}}</td>
    <td>{{program.code2}}</td>
    <td>{{program.ed}}</td>
    <td ng-if="program.status == 'Published' ">{{program.status}}</td>       
    <td ng-if="program.status == 'Draft' ">{{program.status}}</td> 
</tr>
```

i want to display either draft or published according to status.

even when i tried with

1=1
        1=2

both values are getting printed.

Comment: are you sure status contains 'Published' and not something else?

Comment: and what happens...?

Comment: yes also update my question.

Comment: Show us what getProgram contains

Comment: Have you checked what's inside "program.status" ? If there are leading or trailing spaces, comparison logic will fail. You can use "program.status.trim()" in that case.

Comment: Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2127/  Verify that you dont have other issues that lead to ng-If to do not work

Comment: i had tried with ng-show its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CFyvY7JtQQiJIowUCc67?p=preview

this data:

```
![$scope.getProgram = \[{
     name: 'Name1',
     code: 'CodeN1',
     code2: 'Code2N1',
     ed: 'ED',
     status: 'Published'
  }, {
     name: 'Name2',
     code: 'CodeN2',
     code2: 'Code2N2',
     ed: 'ED2',
     status: 'SomeOtherStatus'
  }, {
     name: 'Name3',
     code: 'CodeN3',
     code2: 'Code2N3',
     ed: 'ED3',
     status: 'Draft'
  }, {
     name: 'Name4',
     code: 'CodeN4',
     code2: 'Code2N4',
     ed: 'ED4',
     status: 'NOSHOW'
  }\]][1]
```

Yields this [image: this] result:

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the  `ng-show` in place of `ng-if` and it works for me.

```
 <td ng-show="program.status == 'Published' "><span class="label label-success">{{program.status}}</span></td>
 <td ng-show="program.status == 'Draft'"><span class="label label-warning">{{program.status}}</span></td>
```